# Edge animate unload and reload animations from javascript

Tags: animation, jquery-animate, reload, kill, adobe-edge

I am working on a project, which consists of a slider with 9 slides, where each slide has an edge animation. I already created a script which loads animations in dynamically when you actually land on a particular slide. i did this to avoid loading everything at once. This works fine. However, the issue is that once all 9 animations are in, things start to slow down dramatically.

What I would like to do, is to kill the animation once I leave a corresponding slide and then load it in again, when I come back on to the slide.

The animations are quite complex with symbols being created dynamically and deleting themselves, so I cannot simply stop at 0 on the stage. I have to kill it completely.

If anyone knows a way, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I have managed to instead stop animations via edge javascript api and restart them, when you get back to a corresponding slide. The speed is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797669/prevent-adobe-edge-preload-js-file-from-loading-jquery)**.

Basically you have to modify some file, especially *_edge.js, where you have to bind your custom event:

```
$(window).bind('triggerEdgeAnimation', function () {
    Edge.launchComposition(compId);
});
```

So, somewhere in your code, you can trigger event to start animation:

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
    $(window).trigger("triggerEdgeAnimation");
});
```

Anyway, you can find more details in the link.